# groupby - python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have a dataframe with columns `date`,`name`,`id` (data is redundant).
Now i want to obtain the frequency of combination (`date`,`name`,`id`)
For that am applying `groupby` on my dataframe:

```
df.groupby(['date','uname','id']).size()
```

which is giving me result like:

```
date        uname                id       size                         
2016-02-11  a@abc.com            111       1
            b@abc.com            1080      2
            ar@ata.com           5315      1
                                 5317      1
            aru628@gmail.com     536       2
2-16-02-12  ch45@gmail.com       588       1
                                 593       2    
            doy5@gmail.com       322       1
```

But i want my result to be like:

```
date        uname                id       size                         
2016-02-11  a@abc.com            111       1
2016-02-11  b@abc.com            1080      2
2016-02-11  ar@ata.com           5315      1
2016-02-11  ar@ata.com           5317      1
2016-02-11  aru628@gmail.com     536       2
2-16-02-12  ch45@gmail.com       588       1
2-16-02-12  ch45@gmail.com       593       2    
2-16-02-12  doy5@gmail.com       322       1
```

Appreciate suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.groupby(['date','uname','id']).size().reset_index()

         date             uname    id  size
0  2016-02-11         a@abc.com   111     1
1  2016-02-11         b@abc.com  1080     2
2  2016-02-11        ar@ata.com  5315     1
3  2016-02-11        ar@ata.com  5317     1
4  2016-02-11  aru628@gmail.com   536     2
5  2-16-02-12    ch45@gmail.com   588     1
6  2-16-02-12    ch45@gmail.com   593     2
7  2-16-02-12    doy5@gmail.com   322     1
```

Comment: Oh cool ! I've been checking on reset_index but i dinn try it with some misconception. Thank You !!

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!